# Javascript removeClass() issue

Tags: javascript

Here is the css code :

```
.big-square {
position:relative;
height:768px;
width:768px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color:#007da9;
text-align:center;
display:table-cell;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
```

}

and here the html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
    function showmenu() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#big-square").removeClass("big-square");
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="big-square" onclick="showmenu();" class="big-square">1</div>
    <div id="big-square" onclick="showmenu();" class="big-square">2</div>
```

The problem is when I click on anyone of square, just the first dissapear and I want to make it dissapear separately. For example, if I click on the 2nd square, just the second squuare dissapear.

Comment: first of all, you can't have 2 elements with the same id

Answer (score 4):

`id` must be unique in the whole DOM. (*and the relevant functions return only the first one*)

What you want is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".big-square").on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("big-square");
  });
});
```

```css
.big-square {
  position: relative;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #007da9;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="big-square">1</div>
<div class="big-square">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal HTML to have id's not be unique.  Use a class instead if you plan to have 2 or more elements of similar 'stuff'.  Then, you shouldn't nest the ready statement in a function.  Next, you shouldn't use onclick, instead opting to listen to the event click. Additionally, the css .class does not match an id of your html. Finally to target 1 item only, I would use the jQuery object `$(this)`.

So, all that said, I would re-write your code as:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".big-square").click(function() { 
             $(this).removeClass("big-square");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="big-square" id="square1">1</div>
    <div class="big-square" id="square2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's newbie coding. Let's try to fix it:

1 - Different id's for each element (as user Vic pointed out already)

2 - $(document).ready doesn't need to be nested

3 - onclick="showmenu();" is completely unnecesary and including scripts in the html is bad practice in modern web development

I won't post any code because I see you already have answers with code :)